# parse command line arguments in a different order

Tags: c++, bash, command-line-arguments

I have a small C++ program that reads arguments from the bash. 
Let's say that I have a folder with some files with two different extensions.
Example: file1.ext1 file1.ext2 file2.ext1 file2.ext2 ...

if I execute the program with this command: `./readargs *.ext1`
it will read all the files with the ext1.

if I execute `./readargs *.ext1 *.ext2` it will read all the .ext1 files and then all the .ext2 files.

My question is how can I execute the program in a way that reads with this order: file1.ext1 file1.ext2 file2.ext1 file2.ext2 ... Can I handle that from the command line or I need to handle it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names of your files is really in the form `file1.ext1 file1.ext2 file2.ext1 file2.ext2`, then you can sort it with

```
echo *.{ext1,ext2}|sort -u
```

the above gives the output:

```
$ ll | grep ext
23880775    0 -rw-r--r--  1 user users    0 Apr 29 13:28 file1.ext1
23880789    0 -rw-r--r--  1 user users    0 Apr 29 13:28 file1.ext2
23880787    0 -rw-r--r--  1 user users    0 Apr 29 13:28 file2.ext1
23880784    0 -rw-r--r--  1 user users    0 Apr 29 13:28 file2.ext2
$ echo *.{ext1,ext2} | sort -u
file1.ext1 file2.ext1 file1.ext2 file2.ext2
```

Then you copy the output and call your program. But if you do in fact need the files with `.ext1` before the files of `.ext2`, then you have to either make sure that the `.ext1` is alphabetically inferior to `.ext2` or use another sorting criterion.

Optionally you could also adapt your executable to handle command line arguments in the correct order, but if you do already have an executable I'd recommend the first solution as work-around.

edit: this command does also sort lexically:

```
$echo *.ext[1,2]
$file1.ext1 file1.ext2 file2.ext1 file2.ext2
```

Comment: likewise he should be able to sort the output from his application (which I believe is what he wants) with `myApplication | sort`

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. It gives the same order as before and yes the .ext1 is inferior to .ext2

Comment: add an extra `| tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u` to get the list sorted by sort - when you use the glob it puts them all on the same line, which prevents sort from doing it's sorting magic.

Comment: @John sorry, forgot the `-u` option